# QJSEngine does not know how to handle Qt basic types

Tags: c++, qt, qjsengine

I have a c++/qt application that I made scriptable via a `QJSEngine my_eng` in which I expose my `QWidget my_obj` via `my_eng.globalObject().setProperty("my_obj", my_eng.newQObject(my_obj));`

Now from within JS I can call all methods of `my_obj`. I have a method `getRect()` which returns a `QRectF` and when I call it I get a good representation of it: `QRectF(10, 10, 200, 200)`

Now, if I store this a in variable `my_rect` and try to access it via usual qt methods like `my_rect.setWidth(11)` I get a

`TypeError: Property 'setWidth' of object QRectF(10, 10, 200, 200) is not a function`

Does someone know how to make all qt type available in `QJSEngine`?